# How do I create a given network configuration?

Tags: networking, ip-address

How do I create an eth1 connection with IP address `10.4.6.2`, subnet mask `255.255.255.128(/25)`, with a gateway set as the first available address from the network, and MAC address `AA:BB:CC:DD:4:6` .

I need this set up before (pre-up) starting the interface. Additionally, I have to create a file in `/var/log/journal` which keeps track of every (up and down) state change of the interface (adding the event data at the end of the file).

For example, if I shut down the interface, the file will contain `DOWN [8-12-10/17:55:30]`, with the date written in this format: `[day-month-year/hour:minute:second]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First determine if you can do what you want with network manager, from your post I think that is unlikely.

If you are not going to use Network manager, you will need to either remove it or disable it and understand how to manually configure your network.

```
sudo apt-get remove –purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Bring the network down

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
```

You would then set your nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
sudo -e /etc/resolv.conf
```

You then edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
sudo -e /etc/network/interfaces
```

Something like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.4.6.2
netmask 255.255.255.128
broadcast 111.222.333.444 #I am not sure of your broadcast
gateway your_gateway)ip
```

You can then use the up/down options, the syntax is

```
up <command>
```

So in your case, add in

```
up echo $(date) "eth0 up" >>  /var/log/journal
down echo $(date) "eth0 down" >> /var/log/journal
```

Add those commands in in the eth0 stanza, below gateway.

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/interfaces.5.html

Likewise, date is very flexible, and the options are covered in the man page

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/date.1.html

date +"%d-%m-%y %l:%M:%S"

That at least is going to get you in the ball park.